# How to change .AspNet.Cookies samesite value strict

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

[image: Cookies]

I have an ASP.NET MVC app on .NET 4.7.2. I need to change the `.AspNet.Cookie`'s `samesite` value to `Strict` or `Lax`.

I have tried below scenarios but after use application didn't work.

I have referred following articles but those are not working for me:

[how SameSite attribute added to my Asp.net_SessionID cookie automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59117357/how-samesite-attribute-added-to-my-asp-net-sessionid-cookie-automatically)

[SameSite cookies in ASP.NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840568/samesite-cookies-in-asp-net-4-0)